# strtok not discarding the newline character

Tags: c

so I have an input file with a bunch of names and numbers. I started using strtok to break up the string so that I can extract all the data out of each string. Everything seems to be working correctly, but for some reason it's not discarding the newline character.

```
int procFile(PERSON **data, FILE* fpFile)
{
//  Local Declaration
char temp[1000];
char proc[15];
char *entry;
char *loc;
int success = 0;

//  Statement
if(fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), fpFile))
{
    (*data) = aloMem(); // free
    entry = temp;
    loc = strtok(entry, " ()-");
    strcpy(proc, loc);
    loc = strtok(NULL, " ()-");
    strcat(proc, loc);
    loc = strtok(NULL, " ()-");
    strcat(proc, loc);
    sscanf(proc, "%ld", &(*data)->phone);
    loc = strtok(NULL, "\0");
    strcpy((*data)->name, loc);
    success++;
    printf("%s1", (*data)->name);
}

return success;
}// procFile
```

I tried printing the results to see if it's working correctly and this is my output.

```
Brown, Joanne
1South, Frankie
1Lee, Marie
1Brown, Joanne
1Trapp, Ada Eve
1Trapp, David
1White, D. Robert
1Lee, Victoria
1Marcus, Johnathan
1Walljasper, Bryan
1Trapp, Ada Eve
1Brown, Joanne
1Andrews, Daniel
```

It's printing the `1` after each name on a newline, rather than right after the name. Can someone explain to me how I can fix the problem?

Comment: Removing trailing whitespaces can most portable be done using `strpbrk()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16000784/694576

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before tokenizing `temp`, get rid of the newline as follows:

```
char *newline = strchr( temp, '\n' );
if ( newline )
  *newline = 0;
```

`strchr` searches `temp` for the newline character, and returns a pointer to it (or NULL if the newline character isn't found).  We then overwrite the newline with a 0 (string terminator).

Comment: Or add `\n` to the list of delimiters; no need for a separate scan of the input line then.

Comment: @John Bode:That's a performance hit. You will be scanning the string twice, once for the \n and again for the tokens. While it is perfectly normal for Java and C# programmers to do that, we C++ coders know better :)

Comment: There may be a \r there as well, as in CR LF

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Or, that too.

Comment: @AlexK: Given that this code is I/O bound, I'm not too worried about an extra scan.

Comment: @John Bode: Well if we are not worried about the overhead, lets add two more, one for \r and another one for \t. And this list of exceptions seems to have a tendency to grow...

Comment: @AlexK Before you get sarcastic, you should try out your suggestion. Escaped characters are not recognized in the delimiter string by strtok.

Answer (score 6):

Add \r \n and perhaps \t  to your list of delimiters in strtok

Comment: That does not work.  Escaped characters are not recognized in the delimiter list.

Answer (score 4):

According to `man fgets`:

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer**.

That's where you are getting your newlines from.