# query regarding line feed and fgets()

Tags: c, fgets, gets, linefeed

Code 1:-

```
int main()
{
    char str[200];
    fgets(str,200,stdin);
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:-

```
ab cd
ab cd
(line feed)
```

Code 2:-

```
int main()
{
    char str[200];
    gets(str);
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:-

```
ab cd
ab cd
```

When I enter `ab(space)cd(enter key)` , then in case of `fgets()` I am getting a `line feed` in the output, whereas in case of `gets()`, no new line feed is displayed.
What is the matter of the `line feed` in this case.

Comment: `The newline, if any, is retained.` **man fgets**

Comment: @SakthiKumar : if newline is retained in case of `fgets` then there should be two line feeds in code 1, one for input, another for output, but there is only one

Comment: `printf("%s",str);`. there is no extra `\n` in output i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html)  and [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getchar.3.html) read for a `FILE` in to the buffer provided until a new-line is detected. The former stores a `NUL` **instead** of the new-line, the latter places the `NUL` **after** the new-line.

Please note that `gets()` is **unsafe**, as it does not provide any way to protect writing beyond the limits of the buffer passed.

`fgets()` takes the size of the buffer, and stops reading if this size is reached. In this latter case reading might stop **before** any new-line had been read.

For a general method of chopping of the various kinds of new-lines at the end of a buffer you might like to take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16000784/694576

Comment: I heard that `gets` is disastrous to use, but in this case `fgets` is disastrous, then is there any alternative of `gets` and `fgets`

Comment: I am asking for the alternative, because in my case I do not need newline before nul

Comment: @kevingomes: Please see my even more updated answer.

Comment: one more thing I want to know that why in case of `fgets` I am getting only one `line-feed` in output, there should be two line-feeds , one for input and other for output

Comment: @kevingomes: You enter **one**, you get **one**. In fact its two, as the prompt is **two** new-lines below the last `d`. **One** following the `d`, and **one** producing the empty line, that is **before** the command-line prompt.

Comment: I didn't get you last explanation

Comment: `one following d` means

Comment: There is one new-line after `ab cd`. And one more following the latter, producing the empty line.

Comment: new line should be below `d`, how can it be after `d`

Comment: The new-line character is invisible, you just notice it by the cursor being put on a new line. Everthing after the new-line character is written on a new line.