# Using fopen with input filenames in C

Tags: c, string, file, fopen

At some point in my code, I want to read a name for a file that I will be creating (and/or editing) and I've come up with the following:

```
FILE *fp;
char filename[15];
fgets(filename, 15, stdin);
fp = fopen(filename, "a");
fprintf(fp, "some stuff goes here");
fclose(fp);
```

Even though that does compile and run, it does not create (or open, if I manually create it) the file specified by `filename`.
What would you suggest?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for the file in the correct place.  Also perform a check to see if fp == NULL after you open it.  If it is NULL this means there was an error opening it.  Use the perror function to get the error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File I/O in C using dynamic strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789323/file-i-o-in-c-using-dynamic-strings)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) stores the newline character read from `stdin` after reading a line of input. You need to strip it manually, e.g.

```
size_t len = strlen(filename);
if (len > 0 && filename[len - 1] == '\n')
    filename[len - 1] = '\0';
```

You should also check that `fopen()` doesn't return `NULL`, which it will do if it was unable to open the file. I think using `fprintf` with a `NULL` file pointer is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Usually(but not always), `fgets()` will give you an extra `'\n'` appending the inputted string, because

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a
>   valid character by the function and included in the string copied to
>   str.

<sub>Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/</sub>

To get rid of that `'\n'` using minimal code:

```
fgets(filename, 15, stdin);
filename[strcspn(filename, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `filename[16]` to be able to use 15 characters, you need space for the terminating zero.

Answer (score 0):

Since fgets will read string util an EOF or a newline, and if a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. That means you have to manually trim the ending newline if any. I'd suggest use fscanf instead, it won't add the newline to the buffer:

```
char filename[15];
int ret = fscanf(stdin, "%s", filename);
if (ret != 1) { // handle input error }
fp = fopen(filename, "a");
```

Comment: This won't read a newline into the buffer, but it won't handle filenames with spaces.