# Does these methods of removing '\n' left from fgets differ concerning performance?

Tags: c, performance, escaping, fgets, c-strings

***I'm currently studying C, if this question seems an easy one or a newbie ones, then you know why.***

So, **I know** there are a lot of ways to remove the `'\n'` left by `fgets()`, as already discussed on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443793/fgets-includes-the-newline-at-the-end) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615916/removing-newline-from-fgets).

I'm going to focus this topic about these three methods :

- **char *strchr(const char** *s, **int** c);

  ```
  if (fgets(sentence, 11, stdin) != NULL) {
      p = strchr(sentence, '\n');
      *p = '\0';
  }
  ```
- **char *strtok(char** *str, **const char** *delim);

  ```
  if (fgets(sentence, 11, stdin) != NULL)
      token = strtok(sentence, "\n");
  ```
- **size_t strcspn(const char** *s, **const char** *reject);

  ```
  if (fgets(sentence, 11, stdin) != NULL)
      sentence[strcspn(sentence, "\n")] = '\0';
  ```

Assume that the variables `p` and `token` are declared as `char *p = NULL, *token = NULL;`

They do their job but, as far as performance are concerned, do they differ?

Once, surfing on the web (I'm sorry that I haven't proof of this, because I forgot the link) I found that `strspn` is not a real good way to do that if one is interested in performance, hence my question.

Before posting this on SO I've searched here without finding what I want to know. I've also tried profiling that myself, both using `time ./executable` and [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248915/execution-time-of-c-program) found on SO. However I had no luck, because the results were inconsistent.

Can someone help me finding out if I profiled wrong or if they are really equal?

**EDIT :** [Here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/190504/remove-newline-character-from-a-string) is the link where I found that `strcspn` is not efficient.

Comment: I think this comment in your last link is much more useful: "..the whole operation is I/O bound because of fgets. You can save cycles when stripping the newline, but it isn't likely to have a noticeable effect on performance as a whole". That is, you might be better off focusing your efforts elsewhere.

Comment: @kaylum I wanted to be sure, I've feeling that here on SO you can be sure of what people tells you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method as it is written

```
if (fgets(sentence, 11, stdin) != NULL) {
    p = strchr(sentence,'\n');
    p = '\0';
    //^^ must be *p 
}
```

is incorrect because the new line character can be absent in the string. In this case pointer `p` will be equal to `NULL` and the code snippet will have undefined behaviour.

You need to change it like

```
    if ( p ) *p = '\0';
```

or

```
    if ( ( p = strchr(sentence,'\n') ) != NULL ) *p = '\0';
```

It is efficient enough because only one character is searched.

However its drawback is that you need an additional variable that will point to the new line character.

This method

```
if (fgets(sentence, 11, stdin) != NULL)
    token = strtok(sentence, "\n");
```

semantically is not very suitable. Usually the function `strtok` is used in other context when you need to split a string into tokens.
And the function returns a null pointer in case if the string contains only the new line character.

So the most appropriate method is this

```
if (fgets(sentence, 11, stdin) != NULL)
    sentence[strcspn(sentence, "\n")] = 0;
```

because it is safe and no additional variable is required.

As for me then in C++, I would use

```
if ( char *p = strchr( sentence, '\n' ) ) *p = '\0';
```

and in C, I would use :)

```
sentence[strcspn(sentence, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Comment: @ClaudioCortese Usually it is used to split a string into tokens. You do not want to split a string. You want to remove the new line character.

Comment: You are right, but it does work, as you "tokenize" the entire string taken with fgets removing the '\n' from it.

Comment: @ClaudioCortese Yes it works but it always will take one or two minutes of the reader of the code.:)

Comment: In C++, I'd use `std::getline()` or `std::istream`s `getline()` method which both discard the newline if they find it.     Only a C programmer would use `fgets()` in C++, and need to worry about discarding the newline.

Comment: @ClaudioCortese: `strtok()` is inappropriate because it changes the state of a global hidden variable.  As such, `strtok()` must be used with precautions: Using `strtok()` to strip the newline may break other code surrounding the call to `fgets()` that uses `strtok()` for another purpose and relies of the internal state being preserved between calls. `sentence[strcspn(sentence, "\n")] = '\0';` does not have such side-effects and is preferred.  Furthermore, `strtok()` will not remove the `'\n` if it occurs at the beginning of the array...

Answer (score 4):

Before we discuss performance, it is important to verify correctness.

Let's look at your methods, and some other popular ones:

**strchr**

```
if (fgets(sentence, 11, stdin) != NULL) {
    p = strchr(sentence, '\n');
    *p = '\0';
}
```

You forgot to test if `p` is not `NULL`.  This is a big problem because it is possible that `sentence` does not contain a `\n`, either because the line read was loo long and only part of it is in `sentence` or for the last line in the file if it is not terminated by a `\n`, or if the file contains a null byte.  You should write this version this way:

```
if (fgets(sentence, 11, stdin) != NULL) {
    char *p = strchr(sentence, '\n');
    if (p != NULL)
        *p = '\0';
    ...
}
```

**strchrnul**

Some C libraries have a non standard function `strchrnul` with this prototype:

```
char *strchrnul(const char *s, int c);
```

It returns a pointer to the first occurrence of `c` in the string `s` or a pointer to the final `\0` if no occurrence can be found.  This functions allows for a very simple and efficient way to strip the `\n`:

```
if (fgets(sentence, 11, stdin) != NULL) {
    *strchrnul(sentence, '\n') = '\0';
    ...
}
```

The only drawback is that this function is not part of the C Standard and may not be available on some platforms.

**strtok**

```
if (fgets(sentence, 11, stdin) != NULL) {
    token = strtok(sentence, "\n");
    ...
}
```

This version is incorrect: `strtok` has a side effect on its internal data. This version will interfere with surrounding code that uses `strtok`. If you bury this method in a function, you will hide this side effect and may cause hard to find bugs for programmers using you function.  You could possibly use the reentrant version of `strtok`: `strtok_r`, but it is not always available.

Furthermore, as user3121023 commented, `strtok` will not remove the `\n` if it is at the beginning of the string.  This definitely disqualifies this method.  (`strtok` has too many quirks, it should probably be avoided altogether anyway.)

**strlen**

You did not mention the `strlen` alternative. I see it quite often written this way:

```
if (fgets(sentence, 11, stdin) != NULL) {
    sentence[strlen(sentence) - 1] = '\0';
    ...
}
```

This is incorrect for multiple reasons:

- `sentence` might not have a `\n` as its last character, as already explained for the `strchr` version. Attempting to remove the `\n` this way would remove a valid character.
- `sentence` might be an empty string, in which case the code would have undefined behavior.  For `sentence` to be empty requires exceptional conditions not specified in the C Standard: if the input stream contains a NUL byte at the beginning of a line, `fgets()` might return an empty buffer.

For correctness, this method should be implemented this way:

```
if (fgets(sentence, 11, stdin) != NULL) {
    size_t len = strlen(sentence);
    if (len > 0 && sentence[len - 1] == '\n')
        sentence[--len] = '\0';
    // useful side effect: len has been updated.
    ...
}
```

**strcspn**

```
if (fgets(sentence, 11, stdin) != NULL) {
    sentence[strcspn(sentence, "\n")] = '\0';
    ...
}
```

This is the simplest version.  It works whether `sentence` contains a `\n` or not and even for an empty string.  It is less likely to be misused by a programmer.

**Performance**

Whether `strcspn` is more or less efficient than the other ones depends a lot on the C library implementation and the compiler performance. The performance should be better than that of `strtok`, since it does only one scan.  It is likely less efficient than `strchr` and even less than `strlen`, but for correctness, the `strlen` alternative should also use 2 extra tests for `len > 0` and `sentence[len - 1] == '\n'`, reducing performance.

Note that some libraries use compile-time tests that may allow special casing a 1 byte string literal argument.  In this case, the compiler can generate inline code that would be even more efficient than `strchr`.

It is true that `strcspn` may be implemented in a rather naive way in some C libraries, but this is not the case for the GNU libc, nor for the Apple C Library.  Their implementations are quite efficient, and at least `gcc` uses builtin knowledge of this and other string functions to generate better code.

On environments with an optimized implementation of `strchrnul`, this method should be hard to beat.

As always, run benchmarks and profile the different alternatives with different compilers, processors, C libraries... different platforms may yield very different results.

Comment: For `fgets()` to return an empty string, the first byte on a line after a newline (or the first byte in the file) needs to be a null byte.  That's a problem with `fgets()` — there isn't a way to know how many characters it thinks it read, and if one of the characters it read was a null byte, there's no way to know what else it did read.  From that point of view, the POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) function scores strongly — it tells you how many bytes it read.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: yes, I realized that. It is really a border case. I suspect this to be untested and different C libraries might behave differently to this respect.